# Did Midoriya surpass All Might in his prime in the manga?

Tags: my-hero-academia

So I've been reading and hearing in videos that "Midoriya surpassed All Might in his prime already", presumably after he got some of his last quirks. Is there any statement or proof of this in the manga, or is it just fan speculation?

Comment: There are no claims that support this as of yet, but we can conclude that Midoriya has surpassed All Might in terms of effective power and ability. But on the other hand, in my opinion, Midoriya hasn't surpassed All Might in the raw OFA abilities (excluding past owners of OFA) and strength that All Might had in his prime.